# Compute sum $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x\lambda)^k}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I need to compute this sum: $$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x\lambda)^k}{k!}.$$

I started with the fact that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x\lambda}{n}\right)^n=e^{x\lambda}$$ and $$(a+b)^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}a^kb^{n-k}$$
Then:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x\lambda}{n}\right)^n=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\left( \frac{x\lambda}{n} \right) ^k$$

So I need to find $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  {n \choose k}\left( \frac{x\lambda}{n} \right) ^k = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)}{k!( \frac{n}{x\lambda}) ^k}$$ and what now? In both nominator and denominator I have $n^k$ terms, but it still doesn't help me as I still have a "discrete" polynomial of $k-1$ degree in the nominator. And am I even allowed to go inside the sum with my limit?

Comment: It is just $e^{\lambda x}$

Comment: Isn't it just $e^{\lambda x}$?

Comment: You can divide every term from nominator by $n$ from $n^k$, to get $1(1-1/n)(1-2/n)...(1-(k+1)/n)$, every of multiples is approaching to 1 as $n$ approaching to infinity.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)}{k!( \frac{n}{x\lambda}) ^k}=$
$\frac{(\lambda x)^k}{k!}\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)}{n^k}=$
$\frac{(\lambda x)^k}{k!}\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})...(1-\frac{k+1}{n})=$
$\frac{(\lambda x)^k}{k!}\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{n})
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(1-\frac{2}{n})...
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(1-\frac{k+1}{n})=\frac{(\lambda x)^k}{k!}$

Comment: I know it is $e^{x\lambda}$ but I want to prove that and I don't know if I am allowed to use the relation between sum and $e^x$.

Comment: If you know $e^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}$, then you are allowed to substitute $z=\lambda x$.

Comment: In your case, you can interchange the order of infinite summation and limit because the series converges is "dominated" by a convergent sequence (and hence the dominated convergence theorem is applicable).